# Using Loess npm package with Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I'm trying to import the [Loess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loess) package, which is available via NPM (it's basically an implementation of various regression models to fit data). I've installed it via `npm install loess --save` and it's available in the *node_modules* folder.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to call it's constructor within my component. I use the following import statements in the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as loess from 'loess';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
```

However, I cannot call the constructor in my code,

neither with

```
var model = new loess.Loess(data, options);
```

nor with

```
var model = new Loess(data, options);
```

My developer console always complains about

```
ERROR TypeError: loess.Loess is not a constructor
    at daily.component.ts?5fea:52
```

(or in the other variant with just `new Loess([...])`)

How can I call the constructor of the class within Typescript/Angular? I'm aware that there are no typings available for Loess, but this shouldn't be a problem, should it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the default property from the Loess object.

`let model = new Loess.default(data, options);`

Comment: Code-only answers are often unhelpful in pointing to why the issue happened. Please include an explanation for why your code solves the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)